# How to select a row using shell scripting?

Tags: linux, shell, unix, qnx

Consider the below example:

```
Parameter1 = 5
Parameter2 = 10
Parameter3 = 15
Parameter4 = 20
```

I want to fetch the value depending on the parameter name by providing a user input as shown below:

```
echo ""
echo " Enter the parameter name"
read value
Parameter = "$value"
```

Check if the parameter is existing within the concern file

```
if grep -qs "$Parameter" "Filename"
then 
    echo " Parameter exist within the concern file"
    val = #Here I want to fetch the value of the parameter that the user had input and I do not know how to do it?
```

Kindly let me know how I can fetch the value of the parameter which the user had given as input.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you could use something like this:

```
read param_name # e.g. Parameter2
value=$(awk -v param="$param_name" '$1 == param { print $3 }' filename)
```

This reads the name of the parameter then prints the third field on the line when the first field matches the name. The result is assigned to the shell variable `$value`.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I used the below command which I felt would fetch the correct data. Your input is highly appreciated:

val= kbedit $Filename "p $Object $Parameter" | grep "$Parameter" | awk '{print $3}'

Comment: I don't really get what your comment has to do with the original question. Did you try my suggestion? Did it work? If not, what happened? Please don't post loads of code into comments, it's totally unreadable.